# Changing the output from a text area form based on values from radio buttons in Django - where to start?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm pretty new to Django. I have written a text analysis program which I recently managed to deploy online. The program takes a text input and counts the occurrence of words in the input on a corresponding list, and then returns a score on several different variables.

I want to improve the program by adding radio buttons which allow the user to compare the text input to a desired score.

To exemplify, let's say my categories are "Meat, Fruit, Vegetables, Alcohol". The user provides a list of items from a store, and the program returns a score of how many items belongs to each category.

In this example, I want the user to be able to also decide (using radio buttons) if s/he wants a high, medium or low amount of any of those grocery categories. I then want the program to point out any discrepancies in the output.

The main problem I'm having is that I don't really know where to start. I've tried searching for many variations of this question, but the answers which show up always include a lot of jargon and/or terminology which I'm not familiar with. Similarly, I tried downloading a quiz app project from github to reverse engineer, but I become completely overwhelmed. Even with my best efforts so far I can't even manage to make the radio buttons show up when I try to connect them to a form:

from the html template:

```
<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <input type="radio" name="fruit" style="margin-left: 300px" value="test1" checked> Low
        <input type="radio" name="fruit" style="margin-left: 900px" value="test2" checked> High<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
</form>
```

from views.py:

```
def selector(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Selector(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form_cleaned_data['profile']
    return render(request, 'app/selector.html', {'form': form})
return render(request, 'app/selector.html')
```

from forms.py

```
SCORES = [('low','Low'),]

class Selector(forms.Form):
    ranking = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SCORES, widget = 
forms.RadioSelect)
```

I could easily write this in Python as a desktop program, but the amount of information I get when I try to look for a solution is just overwhelming. I feel like what I need would be a step-by-step tutorial on making a similar web app (for instance - a quiz which gives you a different output based on your radio button choices), but I can't seem to find anything no matter how hard I look. A tutorial which assumes I know nothing and describes even rudimentary terms would be perfect, but anything helps.

Where do I start? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do, but this should help you to display your radio-buttons and provide a decent layout to process the data being submitted. Hopefully it is of some use to you

*template.html*

```
<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for radio in form.ranking %}
        {{ radio }}
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
def selector(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Selector(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.process()  # see forms.py
        return render(request, 'app/selector.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = Selector()
        return render(request, 'app/selector.html', {'form': form})
```

*forms.py*

```
SCORES = [('low','Low'),]

class Selector(forms.Form):
    ranking = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SCORES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def process(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        # process data here (cd)
```